# iPad - SVG colors inverted from desktop

Tags: ios, css, ipad, svg

take a look at the two images below:

**Desktop:**

[image]

iPad:

[image]

Notice the colors of the outer rings? Why are they inverted on the iPad?

```css
.statistic-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 326px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.statistic-container:before {
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.statistic-container svg {
  fill: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.statistic-container__outer-circle {
  stroke: #385fd1;
  stroke-width: 16;
  stroke-dasharray: 1607;
  stroke-dashoffset: -530;
}
.statistic-container__inner-circle {
  stroke: #02158b;
  stroke-width: 16;
  stroke-dasharray: 1607;
}
```

```html
<div class="statistic-wrapper">
  <div class="statistic-container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
      <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="242" class="statistic-container__inner-circle"></circle>
      <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="242" class="statistic-container__outer-circle"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with the dashoffset or possibly the transform...have you tried adjusting that and seeing if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Paulie_D for the tip.

It looks like ipad doesn't play well when you use negative values on `stroke-dashoffset`.

The following fixed my issue:

```
.statistic-container__outer-circle {
  stroke: #385fd1;
  stroke-width: 16;
  stroke-dasharray: 1607;
}

.statistic-container__inner-circle {
  stroke: #02158b;
  stroke-width: 16;
  stroke-dasharray: 1607;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1077;
}
```

I removed the negative offset from the outer circle and added a positive offset on the inner circle.